# How to find dispersion relation for a system of linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find the [dispersion relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) for a system of linear ODEs.

I can do this for a single linear PDE, for example $$u_x = u_t$$
by substituting $u = Ae^{i(kx-wt)}$, here $w = w(k)$ where $k$ is the wavenumber. Then we get

$$(ik) = -iw $$$$\Rightarrow w = -k$$

**However**, now I am trying to find the dispersion relation for a *system* of linear ODEs. For example $$\dot{u_n} =u_{n-1}+u_{n+1}$$ and $n = 1,2,3,...,2N$ when $u_0 = u_{2N}, u_1 = u_{2N+1}$

In the first example, $w$ was a function of a continuous variable $k$. But since there are no $x$ derivatives now, $w$ is a function of a discrete variable $w = w_k$.

**My question**: what do I use to substitute into equation $(1)$ to find the dispersion relation. Would I use the same substitution as the first example? What's confusing me is that we have the term $u_{n-1}$ and I am not sure how we are meant to reflect that in the substitution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is $u_x = u_t$ an ordinary differential equation?

Comment: It's a PDE, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: the system $(1)$ is not closed. you need infinitely many ordinary differential equations.

Comment: I will edit the question now to fix this. Thanks again :)

Comment: @abel, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In electrodynamics it is common to derive dispersion relations for [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_equations), which are a system of linear PDEs, somewhat like your example (but with spatial derivatives). See for example [section 8.3.1 here](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/waves/electromagnetic.pdf).

You can only find dispersion relations for (systems of) differential equations that actually have wavelike solutions, with a wavelength (or wave vector) and a frequency, such that you can find a relation between the two.

Certainly you can insert $u_n=A_n\exp(-i\omega t)$ into your equations. Demanding that a non-trivial solution exist leads to an equation of this form
$$M=\left[\begin{matrix}-i\omega & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -1\\
-1 & -i\omega & -1 &  0 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -i\omega & -1 &  \ldots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \end{matrix}\right]\\
\left|M\right|=0$$
which gives some finite number (probably $2N$) of possible solutions $\omega$. You might call this a "dispersion relation", in the sense that it describes the possible frequencies supported in your "material", but given that your equations are not wave equations this is a bit of a stretch. (If you actually want to calculate this determinant you should look into the theory of [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix))

Now suppose you find an $\omega_i$ that makes $|M|=0$, then you have a solution for the $A_n=\text{ker}(M)$. It is likely so that this $A_n$ is itself of the form $\exp(i k_i n)$ which would let you associate a discrete $k_i$ with $\omega_i$.

OK, in fact we can work this out explicitly. Because $M$ is circulant we have
$$M=W \text{diag}(-i\omega -\Omega_0 -\Omega_0^{2N-1},-i\omega -\Omega_1 -\Omega_1^{2N-1},\ldots) W^{\dagger}$$
where $W$ is a [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), and $\Omega_j=\exp(\frac{\pi i j}{N})$. The discrete solutions $\omega_j$ thus obey
$$-i\omega_j -\Omega_j -\Omega_j^{2N-1}=0$$
$$\omega_j =\frac{\Omega_j +\Omega_j^{2N-1}}{-i}$$
$$\omega_j =\frac{\exp(\frac{\pi i j}{N}) +\exp(\frac{\pi i j}{N})^{2N-1}}{-i}$$
$$\omega_j =2 i \cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{N}\right)$$
The corresponding eigenvector in the nullspace is a column of $W$:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}A_1 \\ A_2 \\ \vdots \\A_{2N}\end{matrix}\right]\propto\left[\begin{matrix}\exp\left(\frac{0 \pi i j}{N}\right) \\ \exp\left(\frac{1 \pi i j}{N}\right) \\ \vdots \\ \exp\left(\frac{(2N-1) \pi i j}{N}\right) \end{matrix}\right]$$
which has $k=\pi j/N$.

Thus, your dispersion relation is $(\omega_j,k_j)=\left(2 i \cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{N}\right),\pi j/N\right)$

Comment: Well they are a system of linear coupled PDEs (which can of course be uncoupled). But good example (for the physicist in me). Another one is the finite/infinite chain of masses connected by springs

Comment: It's not that there is no $k$. It's that $k$ is now discrete.

Comment: In that case every (discrete) $\omega$ solution will correspond to a discrete $k$ which you can get from the nullspace of the matrix.

Comment: Why did you add the term $A_n$?

Comment: In the case of Maxwell's equations, you would use $E=A_e\exp(i k x-i\omega t)$, $B=A_b\exp(i k x-i\omega t)$, and you don't know $A_e$, $A_b$ in advance. You do get a connection between them once you have the dispersion relation. Eventually, every point on the dispersion relation corresponds to a (usually) one-dimensional solution space, specified up to amplitude. It might be that this is overkill, that your problem can be solved somehow without introducing $2N$ degrees of freedom $A_n$, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Where did you get $k$ from?

Comment: By looking at the nullspace corresponding to an $\omega_j$ solution, you get a solution for the $A_n$, which happens to be a complex exponential in $n$ : $A_n\propto \exp((n-1)i \pi  j / N)$. It is reasonable to interpret the factor $\pi  j / N$ in there as a "wavenumber" w.r.t. the index $j$, just as you would interpret the $k$ in $\exp(i k x)$ as a wavenumber w.r.t $x$.